# Python: How do I estimate the total memory my algorithm will use?

Tags: python, memory, split

My algorithm reads first a huge sample of texts. Next, I need to split them into lines:

```
texts = file_content.split("\n")
```

However, the file is so big that the process immediately goes into SWAP.
I'd like to predict, how much memory I actually need. 
Is that possible?

Comment: Do you *have* to have random access to all the lines, you can't process them line by line instead?

Comment: That is dependent on the number of newlines in the file, but you need at least 2x as much memory as the size of the file.  Why aren't you just reading the file line-by-line to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

It may be helpful to figure out the size of the file in bytes before you proceed. This will probably give you a rough estimate of the amount of memory you will then need.

To get the size of a file, you could use the `getsize(path` method from `os.path`.

```
import os
size_in_bytes = os.path.getsize('file.txt')
```

However, you'll probably need twice as much memory of the file size - you'll store the file in memory, as well as the strings that are read from the file.

As Kasra points out, you're better off to read the file line by line through something like an iterator (just the `open()` method), and perform processing line by line, reducing the need for extra memory.

For example:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    process(line)
```

Comment: Interesting points indeed... You think you could jump into [this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107475/talk) chat room to discuss a few things?

Answer (score 0):

1 Thing is just to optimize your code, but you asked about the memory usage. You can see here a good article http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2013/different-ways-to-get-memory-consumption-or-lessons-learned-from-memory_profiler/ . With library psutil you just get with these line of code the memory usage

```
import os
import psutil
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print process.memory_info().rss
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to predicate the amount of memory which your algorithm supposed to use. But instead of reading whole of the text at once and loading it up in memory as a more pythonic way you can use `open()` that will return a file object which is an iterator like object and doesn't waste your memory. And you can access to the lines simply by looping over the file object.